# How do I mock a class property with mox?

Tags: python, mocking, properties, mox

I have a class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @property
    def myproperty(self):
        return 'hello'
```

Using [`mox`](http://code.google.com/p/pymox/) and `py.test`, how do I mock out `myproperty`?

I've tried:

```
mock.StubOutWithMock(myclass, 'myproperty')
myclass.myproperty = 'goodbye'
```

and

```
mock.StubOutWithMock(myclass, 'myproperty')
myclass.myproperty.AndReturns('goodbye')
```

but both fail with `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: Please use Upper Case Names for Classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When stubbing out class attributes `mox` uses `setattr`. Thus

```
mock.StubOutWithMock(myinstance, 'myproperty')
myinstance.myproperty = 'goodbye'
```

is equivalent to

```
# Save old attribute so it can be replaced during teardown
saved = getattr(myinstance, 'myproperty')
# Replace the existing attribute with a mock
mocked = MockAnything()
setattr(myinstance, 'myproperty', mocked)
```

Note that because `myproperty` is a property `getattr` and `setattr` will be invoking the property's `__get__` and `__set__` methods, rather than actually "mocking out" the property itself.

Thus to get your desired outcome you just go one step deeper and mock out the property on the instance's class.

```
mock.StubOutWithMock(myinstance.__class__, 'myproperty')
myinstance.myproperty = 'goodbye'
```

Note that this might cause issues if you wish to concurrently mock multiple instances of MyClass with different `myproperty` values.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read about [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)?  It's read-only, a "getter".

If you want a setter, you have two choices of how to create that.

Once you have both getter and setter, you can try again to mock out both of them.

```
class MyClass(object): # Upper Case Names for Classes.
    @property
    def myproperty(self):
        return 'hello'
    @myproperty.setter
    def myproperty(self,value):
        self.someValue= value
```

Or

```
class MyClass(object): # Upper Case Names for Classes.
    def getProperty(self):
        return 'hello'
    def setProperty(self,value):
        self.someValue= value
    myproperty= property( getProperty, setProperty )
```

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to get away with not modifying the original class, may not be possible though.

Comment: You can't mock something that doesn't exist.  The original class could not have the property set.  You cannot mock that feature because it does not exist.